# Ajax including a page

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can I make some functions on a loaded page from Ajax?
I.E.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "loaded.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
    $("a#edit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newVal = $(this).closest("tr").find("#collapse").html();
        $(this).html(newVal);
    });
});
```

Both `a#edit` and `#collapse` are elements of the loaded.php and this code is in the index.php page... Will this code work?

Comment: Have you considered just running it and finding out?

Comment: I wouldn't be asking here if I hadn't tried :D, but maybe I have done something wrong, that's why I am asking here ;), if you need the full code I'll post it ;)

Comment: You should probably ask a question other than "will this code work?" if that is not the answer you're looking for...

Comment: As a general suggestion to both asker and answerers: look at [`$.Deferred()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) if you want to chain multiple pieces of functionality to an [`$.ajax(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options attaching the handler in the success function after you add the html to `#content` or use delegation.

Option 1

```
    success: function(data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
        $("#edit").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
           var newVal = $(this).closest("tr").find("#collapse").html();
           $(this).html(newVal);
        });
    }
```

option 2

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "loaded.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
    $("#content").on('click', '#edit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var newVal = $(this).closest("tr").find("#collapse").html();
        $(this).html(newVal);
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

If your $("a#edit") element is something returned by your ajax, then no this code will not work. You need to move that block of code into the success callback.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "loaded.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
            $("a#edit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var newVal = $(this).closest("tr").find("#collapse").html();
                $(this).html(newVal);
            });
        }
    });
});
```