# How to bind events to HTML injected from AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

So I am injecting `html` via an AJAX request:

**Ajax Response**

```
  <div id="my-element">HTML from AJAX request</div>
```

The problem is that the element with id `#my-element` comes in from the AJAX request, but I need to bind events too it. For example:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my-element").click(function() {
        alert("hit");
    });
 });
```

Obviously the event above never fires, because when the page is ready, the HTML has not been injected from the AJAX request yet. What is the best solution to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: similiar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976236/ajax-including-a-page

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind a function to Element loaded via Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116170/how-to-bind-a-function-to-element-loaded-via-ajax)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use `jQuery.on` function: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).on('click', '#my-element', function () { ... });
```

Then it will work even with dinamically added elements.

Answer (score 0):

Add your event after injecting html via an AJAX request has been completed
or
 you can use `on` method

see this example also

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/jquery-event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: But then I have to manage the events, because everytime the AJAX request is fired, it is going to bind another event. I.E. the AJAX request gets called every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `on` method to make it live.

```
$(function(){
    $("#my-element").on("click",function() {
        alert("hit");
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Do the binding in the success callback of your ajax call, after you ahve inserted the html into the DOM.